# How do I revert only specific lines from a specific file?

Tags: linux, git, revert

Suppose that several commits ago I deleted a bunch of code, and now I want *some* of that code back.

For a while now I've been using [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), which allows you to simply select the lines you want back from the earlier commit and select "Revert selected lines" (or something like that). Now I'm working in Linux and can't find a GUI with any such feature; so I'm wondering how one might achieve this from the command line.

The first option that comes to mind would be to revert the entire commit, then amend it to only include the code I want back. Is there an easier/better way?

Comment: You could use the command line, e.g. `git show` to retrieve the older commit... You could also use the VC menu of GNU `emacs`

Answer (score 4):

An idea is like you already said:

undo the commit, reset it, then re-add the file but using the option -p so that you can choose which line you want.

an example:

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
git reset HEAD fileA
git add -p fileA
...
commit here
```

Comment: You can also use `git checkout -p HEAD^` which will give you the same interactive editor, but in reverse.